# how to delete abandoned sheet after unreadable content repair?

Tags: vba, excel

My question: how do I delete a sheet in an Excel workbook that has been 'abandoned' by Excel? The sheets I am trying to remove that have been 'abandoned' are the ones in the screen shot below that have a little green 'x' on them.

Details:

Every once in a while I get unreadable content errors in Excel, the ultimate cause of most of these is unknown (despite investing countless hours trying to sort it out). I'm happy to receive pointers on unreadable content errors, but I have probably read every suggestion that is available online at least twice. I digress...  Anyway, when I get the "unreadable content" pop-up and I repair by clicking Yes, Excel (seemingly) creates a new duplicate repaired sheet of the erroneous sheet in my workbook and abandons all of the code in the old sheet object. So in the end, after repairing I am left with what I am calling an 'abandoned' sheet with a little green 'x' on the sheet object shown in the Project explorer which is not accessible (as far as I know). I am also left with a new sheet that is 'repaired', but doesn't contain any of the sheet object code. How do I delete the sheets with the green x on them?

For example, I say abandoned because this returns '7', when there are clearly more than 7 sheet objects in the project viewer screen shot below:

```
Sub test()
Debug.Print Sheets.Count
End Sub
```

Further, the code below returns "Values" which is now the second sheet, so how do I access/delete the Sheet1 in the project viewer screen shot below:

```
Sub test()
Debug.Print Sheets(1).Name
End Sub
```

[image: Project Explorer]

Comment: FWIW, the "little green x" indicates `Workbook` objects, not sheets.   And yes, there should only be one.  The presence of multple "x"'s indicates your workbook is corrupt (and an eventual crash is inevitable).  I know, no real help here!  A better question might be on how the workbook gets in this state: some info on the buildup to this situation _might_ yield some real help.  Given it's a xlsm, investigating the xml might reveal something.

Comment: @chrisneilsen thanks. I posted about unreadable content directly in a previous post and I didn't even get a comment on it so I went a different direction. I sorted out some of the issues, but some allude me and everyone I have asked still. I have given up and have resorted to treating the symptoms.

Comment: Is that your _can I safely to delete..._ question from July?  I saw that, thought it might be related.  I ran a little test: a wb with a sheet with one button and your delete code.  _Seems_ to run ok, without corrupting the workbook, but my gut feel is deleteing the container of running code is dangerous (nothing to support that, but still...)

Comment: @chrisneilsen now that I am looking at my past questions I think I deleted my question because it received some down votes and no answers, but I'm not sure. Or maybe I never asked it because it was so vague and I had no code to provide. ANYWAY, I know that if I change the number formats manually via the Excel tool bar for certain unknown cells I get the unreadable content error the next time I open the file. I never know it until after the fact. That's all I have. I am pretty sure that question would get hammered on this forum. I don't do what you describe above. I decided it wasn't good too.